# Second Generation Nest Cams Missing Permissions on Consent Screen

Tags: nest-device-access

When authorizing your application, second generation Nest cams (in this case an indoor/wired) do not appear to have all the necessary permissions.

[example from consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUHuu.png)

Note that the Basement camera (first generation indoor) has the "Based on the events you've selected..." permission. While the Office camera does not.

Indeed, attempting to download event images for the Office camera results in "ACCESS_DENIED" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new cameras do not support snapshots in Device Access, which is why that's missing.

https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/supported-devices

Comment: I hadn't seen that, thank you.  Why the new wired cameras don't support it is puzzling... it's not like they will run out of battery.